# How to create not repeat pairs using option input types and jQuery + UnderscoreJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js

I need to create a non repeated pair of values using option input types and jQuery. I'm doing in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $modelBranch = {};

    $("#create").on("click", function () {
        var $model = $("#modeloBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
        var $branch = $("#marcaBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    });
});
```

This is the HTML code where I'm applying the code:

```
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
    <legend class="rpni-border">Model</legend>
    <table id="contenedorModelos" style="" class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody id="modeloBody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id="selModelo1" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Harum.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="4" id="selModelo4" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Pariatur ut.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="6" id="selModelo6" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Tempore animi.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="8" id="selModelo8" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Voluptatem.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
    <legend class="rpni-border">Branch</legend>
    <table id="contenedorMarcas" style="" class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody id="marcaBody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id="selMarca3" name="selMarcas">
                </td>
                <td>Ea in sequi.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="7" id="selMarca7" name="selMarcas">
                </td>
                <td>Exercitationem.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="11" id="selMarca11" name="selMarcas">
                </td>
                <td>Sit alias sit.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<button id="create" type="button">Create</button>
<div id="ModelBranch"></div>
```

What I need to do is pick one option from Model, pick one option from Branch and on click event for the button create the pair and add the values for each option in `key => value` way to the `$modelBranch` vars so any time I add a new one first check if values are already added. Now, since UnderscoreJS is a nice library to work with array, objects and so on I'm planning to use it instead of use just jQuery and Javascript. So, how do I create the array with pairs like for example:

```
[
 {
    "model" => 1, 
    "branch" => 1
 },

 {
    "model" => 2, 
    "branch" => 1
 },

 {
    "model" => 2, 
    "branch" => 2
 },
]
```

And then how I find if a pair already exists on that array so I will not add it to it again and stop code execution?
And how to add them to the array as I have think? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/3ygyvk0j/2/) is a Fiddle to play with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var
  //to check whether it is a duplicate, easier than checking by iteration
    map = {},
    //to store the result
    array = [];

  $("#create").on("click", function() {
    var model = $("#modeloBody").find("input[name=selModelos]:checked").val();
    var marca = $("#marcaBody").find("input[name=selMarcas]:checked").val();
    //only if both options are selected
    if (model && marca) {
      var key = model + '-' + marca;
      //only if the item is not present
      if (!map[key]) {
        //mark the combination as added
        map[key] = true;
        array.push({
          model: model,
          maca: marca
        });
      }
    }
    //print the result
    $('#ModelBranch').html(JSON.stringify(array))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
  <legend class="rpni-border">Model</legend>
  <table id="contenedorModelos" style="" class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody id="modeloBody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="1" id="selModelo1" name="selModelos">
        </td>
        <td>Harum.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="4" id="selModelo4" name="selModelos">
        </td>
        <td>Pariatur ut.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="6" id="selModelo6" name="selModelos">
        </td>
        <td>Tempore animi.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="8" id="selModelo8" name="selModelos">
        </td>
        <td>Voluptatem.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
  <legend class="rpni-border">Branch</legend>
  <table id="contenedorMarcas" style="" class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody id="marcaBody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="3" id="selMarca3" name="selMarcas">
        </td>
        <td>Ea in sequi.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="7" id="selMarca7" name="selMarcas">
        </td>
        <td>Exercitationem.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="11" id="selMarca11" name="selMarcas">
        </td>
        <td>Sit alias sit.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<button id="create" type="button">Create</button>
<div id="ModelBranch"></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution but I'll need to add some extra level. If you take a look to the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/3ygyvk0j/4/) I've added another `fieldset` called "Manufacturer". What I need? in `div#ModelBranch` place one row per pair and add a checkbox at first so later I can pick one or more pairs and also pick one or more manufactures and repeat the process, create new pairs but this time containing model/branch-manufacturer, can you help me on this one too?